# How to send WebKitFormBoundary in multipart

Tags: karate

I using postman to run upload file api and it's OK, But i tried with karate with multipart but not work.
So i compared postman request and karate request i saw the different is '----WebKitFormBoundary', so how to add this in karate?

And multipart file users_file = {value: '#(data)', filename: '#(filename)'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to customize the  '----WebKitFormBoundary'. It is an HTTP standard and different HTTP clients can use different names.

It is *impossible* to say what you are doing wrong with the limited information you have provided. So my best suggestion to you is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Or search the other questions for Karate and multipart: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+multipart